# PHP Page As Image Source?

Tags: php, image, mysqli

As the title suggests, I'm currently using a PHP page as an image tag's "src" attribute.

The images are stored in a "Questions" MySQL table, as MEDIUMBLOBs (There are other, better, ways of storing images, but there's no wiggle room for me here unfortunately).

I echo out the image like so:

```
 echo("<img src=\"teacherPageQuestionsImage.php?id=" . $_row["Question_ID"] . "\">");
```

The page "teacherPageQuestionsImage" itself is the following code:

```
<?php

require 'databaseConnect.php';

session_start();

if (!isset($_SESSION['valid_teacher']))
{
    header("Location:teacherLoginPage.php");
}

if(isset($_GET['id']))
{
    $_questionID = $_GET['id'];

    // Open DB Connection
    $_conn = databaseConnect();

    $_stmt = $_conn->prepare("SELECT Question_Image FROM Question WHERE Question_ID=?");
    $_stmt->bind_param("i",$_questionID);

    $_stmt->execute();
    $_stmt->store_result();
    $_stmt->bind_result($_image);
    $_stmt->fetch();

    // Close DB Connection
    $_conn->close();

    header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");
    echo($_image);   
}

?>
```

This works, but only on Desktop Chrome.
[image: See Image]

On Mobile Chrome (Android) and other browsers (IE, Edge), it doesn't work - the "image not found" icon displayed.
[image: See Image]

The Image is inserted into the database like this:

```
$_imagePost = file_get_contents($_FILES['_imagePost']['tmp_name']);

// Open DB Connection
$_conn = databaseConnect();

$_stmt = $_conn->prepare("INSERT INTO Question (Question_Type, Question_Text, Question_Answer, Question_UseImage, Question_Image) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
$_stmt->bind_param("sssib", $_typePost, $_textPost, $_answerPost, $_useImagePost, $_null);
$_stmt->send_long_data(4,$_imagePost);
$_stmt->execute();

$_idPost = $_conn->insert_id;

// Close DB Connection
$_conn->close();
```

So what exactly is causing problems? Why do the images display fine on Chrome Desktop, but not render at all on other browsers and mobile Chrome (Android).

Comment: Are you sending the proper image header response to tell the browser that the content you are about to display is an image type X?

Comment: Any errors in the browser console when it doesn't work?

Comment: Try opening the image directly in a browser - what happens when you run it in a browser that doesn't show it inline?

Comment: @OliverQueen You mean this line? `header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");`

Comment: Is this a public website we can access?

Comment: are you sure that image is actually jpeg? maybe its png/gif?

Comment: also, take a look how to store blobs properly: https://blogs.oracle.com/oswald/entry/php_s_mysqli_extension_storing

Comment: It is a PNG in this case. However, uploading a JPEG also causes the same issue.
@OliverQueen How can I tell when pulling the image out of the database what type it is? 
Barmar - I'm not confident enough in security to make it public yet, sorry!

Comment: uploading of real jpeg (not just rename) - will not cause the same issue

Comment: @W.H - when the file is uploading, you will get an array that tells the content type of the image

Comment: That being said, I would also suggest you check that and the contents of the file BEFORE displaying it, especially on a PHP page.

Comment: @Lashane Uploading a "real" jpeg causes the same issues unfrotunately.

Comment: @OliverQueen are there any guides to doing this (checking)? Is it as simple as adding ['type'] to $_imagePost = file_get_contents($_FILES['_imagePost']['tmp_name']); ?

Comment: I'd highly advise against uploading and inserting into a database until you fully understand what is going on. That said, http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp is a great jump off point

Comment: @OliverQueen Thanks! 
I do broadly understand what's going on, surely there's no better way of learning than doing?

Comment: @W.H - I fully agree with that! I'm glad I could help!

Comment: @W.H uploading of real jpeg, clearing cache and checking http headers - will work